# Mark an Active Directory Object as "Read-Only"?

Tags: windows, dns, active-directory, privileges

We had a bad day yesterday.  One of our Domain Admins deleted an OU containing 700+ users and the same amount of computers as well as assorted other useful things like groups etc.

We restored from a backup, but it wasn't pretty.

I know that ADUC asks you if you're sure etc... but I'd like it if it was not possible to delete this particular OU without going into something like ADSIEdit to set it "allowable" for deletion - thereby not allowing people to delete without actually opening a new app and specifically indicating that "YES - I know what I'm doing".  This would have the added benefit of stopping accidental miscoding from deleting critical AD objects.

Any such attribute or method that you folks could think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the permission to delete things from those unable to get it right. You can give very fine-grained permissions in AD.

There is no "readonly" attribute. That's what the [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) are for.

Comment: I think we're going to go this route.

Basically on the critical objects we're going to add Domain Users with "DENY DELETE" on THIS OBJECT ONLY.

If we want to delete it at some point, we then will go in and remove this ACL and delete.

Comment: Or they'll have ask someone/log on as someone who is not denied deleting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in AD for Win2k3 and higher to mark an object to prevent accidental deletion.  This check box on the object actually changes the underlying permissions for you to remove delete permissions.  Therefore it is not tool specific and must be respected by other tools (like powershell and vbscript).

Answer (score 0):

You could deny the Delete privalge from Administrators through Delegation at the root level and then you would need to be an enterprise admin to perform deletions. Ensure that no admins are in the Enterprise Admins group for day-to-day usage.